# css orphan detector?

Tags: css

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a tool that will help me identify obsolete css (declared styles that never get used) in my site. 
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [CSS cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285442/css-cleaner) here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Since stylesheets can be added with script, and elements and classes can be created with scripts, it could be risky to remove css class and id declarations if they are not found in the html of those pages that literally link to those stylesheets.

That said, perl is a good tool for any kind of sitewide search and replace operation.